# About a proof of the bordered Hessian test.

Tags: optimization, determinant, hessian-matrix

I was trying to find a proof of the bordered hessian test for optimization problems with constraints but the only thing I found was:

> z' H z <= 0 for all z satisfying Σi gi zi = 0 where H is the bordered Hessian and gi are the partial derivative of the constraint g=0.
> This requires that the border-preserving principle minors determinants alternate in sign. I.e., the 3 x 3 determinant (including the border) is positive, the 4 x 4 determinant is negative, and so on.

Where can I find a proof of this test or how do I proceed to prove this test?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @angryavian I know it but Sylvester criterion isn't used for unconstrained optimization? Or am I misunderstanding it?